# How to send a reply from a notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm doing an app that manages the received notifications. Currently, I'm implementing a feature that the user can reply through the reply action, but I couldn't find a way to properly set the reply message and send the message.

Here is what I have tried

```
fun sendReplyMessage(sbn: StatusBarNotification, replyMessage: String) {
    sbn.notification.actions.firstOrNull { it.remoteInputs != null }?.let { action ->
        action.remoteInputs?.get(0)?.extras
            ?.putCharSequence(action.remoteInputs?.get(0)?.resultKey, replyMessage)
        action.actionIntent.send()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the notification action to access the pending intent, add the remote input on this intent, and then, call the method PendingIntent#send(context, requestCode, intent)

```
val notificationAction: android.app.Notification.Action = "Get the Action here"

val bundle = Bundle().apply{
     putString(remoteInput.resultKey, "Add the text here")
}

val intent = Intent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND)

RemoteInput.addResultsToIntent(notificationAction.getRemoteInputs(), intent, bundle)

notificationAction.actionIntent.send(context, 0, intent)
```